# Does a stationary wave carry energy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, waves

My teacher said stationary waves have energy but do not carry energy. So I am confused with it.

Questions:

1. What is a stationary wave?
2. Does a stationary wave carry energy?
3. What is the energy equation of stationary wave?

Comment: You should read this : http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/standw.html and this http://www.kshitij-iitjee.com/Standing-Waves

Answer (score 1):

For clarity in answering your questions, it is worth recapping what the group and phase velocities of a wave are:

- The group velocity $v_{g}$ is the rate at which the overall shape (*envelope*) of the wave propagates through space, and what might classically be thought of as the speed of the wave. For 1D waves the group velocity is given by the derivative of the wave's angular momentum with respect to its wavenumber, i.e. $v_{g} = \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial k},$ whereas 3D waves are given by $\mathbf{v_{g}} = \nabla_{\mathbf{k}} \omega$, where $\nabla_{\mathbf{k}}$ is the gradient with respect to the wavevector $\mathbf{k}$ coordinates.
- Phase velocity $v_{p}$ is the rate at which the phase of the wave propagates through space, i.e. the velocity of the underlying structure. In 1D this is given by the ratio of the angular frequency to the wavenumber, i.e. $v_{p} = \frac{\omega}{k}$. The 3D case is very similar, being given by $\mathbf{v_{p}} = \mathbf{\hat{k}} \frac{\omega}{\lvert \mathbf{k} \rvert}$, where $\mathbf{\hat{k}}$ and $\lvert \mathbf{k} \rvert$ are the unit vector and magnitude of the wavevector, respectively.

With those covered, the answers to your questions:

1. A wave that is stationary (or *standing*) is one for which the group velocity is zero. This means that the overall shape of the wave remains unmoving in a longitudinal direction, however the wave can still oscillate transversely, i.e. perpendicular to the direction of (non)travel.
2. Stationary waves are motion, thus must have associated energy, however due to the longitudinal stationarity of the wave, energy cannot be transported in that direction and so may only be transferred transversely.
3. The total energy of a wave is the sum of its kinetic and potential energies i.e. $E_{\text{tot}} = E_{\text{k}} + E_{\text{p}}$, where the former term is related to the group velocity as $E_{\text{k}} \propto v_{g}^{2}$. As a result, for stationary waves $E_{\text{tot}} = E_{\text{p}}$ and so if one knows the total energy of the system then one also knows the potential energy of the system (and vice versa). The full form of the equation is situation dependent, for instance the energy equation for a particle in a box is completely different to that of an electron wave in a plasma, though both are stationary waves.